# Debugging C++ in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, debugging, linked-list

After using Visual Studio for a week, I find CodeBlocks and other IDEs in Linux far inferior. I don't know if I am missing something, but I would love to have an IDE like VS in Linux. I have tried gdb, but I find it difficult to use.
For instance, is there anything in Linux that can inspect values of a linked list like how Visual Studio shows.

[image]

I need to try out DDD. (the interface looks so 1980s :()

Comment: Are you developing the C++ in an IDE?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79023/c-gdb-gui

Comment: You should work on your gdb foo, that way you can be a real linux user not just a windows, linux user.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the [Data Display Debugger](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddd/), or DDD, displays data structures graphically while debugging. Having said that, if you are writing your own linked list class in C++, you are not really taking full advantage of the language.  Why not use the already fully-debugged std::list?

Comment: I got to say I don't find DDD as intuitive as Visual Studios.  Not gone through the manual - but didn't need to for VS. (I do not like saying this...)

Comment: @Tom - don't feel bad saying it.  Everyone privately thinks it but no one wants to talk about it.

Comment: The last time I used ddd, it was so buggy that I just learned gdb command line interface and never looked at ddd again.

Answer (score 3):

[Nemiver](http://projects.gnome.org/nemiver/) is a standalone graphical debugger for C and C++. It is actively maintained and has lots of features a modern debugger should have: setting breakpoints, watchpoints, stepping through code, inspecting memory and registers, tooltips showing contents of variables, integrated disassembler, source files are displayed with syntax highlighting, and so on.

Comment: How well does it handle visualizing STL containers?

Comment: Nemiver's next release is going to have support for pretty-printing standard STL containers. See the latest status report: https://mail.gnome.org/archives/nemiver-list/2011-March/msg00001.html

Comment: Interesting.  It seems like a good start.  Is there a manual somewhere?  How does it handle threads?  Is there a way to open a watch window?

Answer (score 2):

Surprised no on-ones mentioned Eclipse with CDT.  Having used VS for years before migrating to Linux, I found it to be just as competent.

Comment: How do the STL container visualizations compare?

Comment: A picture paints a thousand words: http://www.cam-bamber.co.uk/other/Screenshot.jpg.  You need to do this first though: http://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/STLSupport

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you to check out KDevelop and Qt Creator.

They've got a graphical debugger (it's just a GDB IDE, just like DDD) which lets you surf through class fields and pointers just like in your example.

Answer (score 0):

The shortest possible answer is: yes there are IDE's that work on Linux, but I have never seen anything that comes close to Visual Studio when it comes to debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Try Netbeans with the C++ plugin. I find it very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Now You just need Clion from JetBrain, more productivity and easy debugging.

Answer (score -2):

Check out [MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/) as well. It is designed to be very similar to Visual Studio.