# Is there a UI for GDB that connects to a device?

Tags: c++, gdb, remote-debugging, embedded-linux

I'm using GDB on my PC to connect to GDBServer on my device (which uses an iMX51) and I can debug fine. But can any of the GDB UIs I've heard about (e.g. in [C++ gdb GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79023/c-gdb-gui)) be used for this?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Eclipse to remote debug using GDB.

Roughly the process looks like this:

1. Start by install Eclipse CDT.
2. Install the C/C++ GNU Toolchain Debug Support and Eclipse Debugger for C/C++ add-ins.
3. Create a debug configuration for your project (Run->Debug Configurations)
4. Point to the cross compiler's GDB executable(e.g. if you use CodeSourcery that would be bin/xxxx-gdb ).
5. In the debugger tab select "gdbserver" and enter the remote target details.
6. Create a gdb init command file to set up your sysroot, library paths, and point gdb to your executable with the file command.

If you google for remote gdb debugging using Eclipse you'll be able to find more information.