# Graphical debugger interface on CentOS 7

Tags: linux, centos, gdb, kdbg

Can anybody help suggesting good graphical debugger interface for CentOS 7. I tried searching for kdbg which works well on Ubuntu but there is no help available for installing kdbg and dependencies on CentOS 7. I tried installing kdbg rpm manually but then it doesn't work because a lot of dependencies like libDCOP.so, libkdcore.so, libkio.so etc. are not installed.

 Is there a way to install kdbg and all of its required dependencies at once ? I am a newbie to CentOS and any help for this is appreciated.

Comment: Read up on the "apt-get" (or any other variant) that is installed on your system.

Comment: the varient is yum..but I don't know how that's related ? I tried doing sudo yum install kdbg..but that didn't work

Comment: It matters because yum (or apt-get) will install an application with all it's dependencies... that is your question right?

Comment: the question is kdbg for cent os 7 is not there in yum repositories. Hence I downloaded the rpm manually and tried to install it. the rpm doesn't have any dependencies in it.

Answer (score 0):

*It's been two years but this Q is still unanswered, hasn't been closed, and should still apply*:

## 1) Try [Nemiver](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Nemiver)

From the webpage:

> Nemiver is an on going effort to write an easy to use standalone C/C++ debugger that integrates well in the GNOME environment.

It's extremely simple and straightforward. And it should be available for CentOS 7 (I have a box with CentOS 6.8 and it's available via `yum`).

## 2) Read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79023/is-there-a-c-gdb-gui-for-linux)

*Is there a C++ gdb GUI for Linux?*

Be warned, that question was closed as off-topic.

## 3) Perhaps a full IDE like [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/)?

You get the whole package: a text editor, one-click building, plugins, and a graphical debugger.